# solve triangle law of signs

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

Height of a Tree A tree on a hillside casts a shadow
215 ft down the hill. If the angle of inclination of the
hillside is 22 to the horizontal and the angle of elevation
of the sun is 52, find the height of the tree.

[image]

I do not understand how to solve this problem, any help would be much appreciated (note: i do have the answer to the question, so it is the steps to achieve that answer is what i am interested in) . 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[image]
First, draw a diagram.
Second, try to find all of the missing angles. What is $52^{\circ}-22^{\circ}$?
Next, use the trig definitions to find some of the missing sides. One of those sides is the tree; come up with a strategy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you know the hypothenuse (215 ft)... So use 215 ft x sin22 and 215 ft x cos22 to find the sides of the right triangle... Then use the base and tan52 to find the length of "215 ft sin22 + tree"... You are done...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Consider my absolutely horrible drawing. The sun is $55º $ of inclination over the horizontal. The hill is $22º$ of inclination over the horizontal. Therefore the angle formed between the base of the tree, the base of the hill and the sun is $55º-22º=33º.$ Now, consider the angle $\beta$. We know that $\beta + 55º +90º = 180º \Rightarrow \beta = 35º$. Now use the law of sines:

$$\frac{\sin 33º}{h} = \frac{\sin\beta}{215 ft}.$$

PD: Oops! I read the angle of elevation of the sun was $55º$ instead of $52º$. I won't re-draw. Just change everything in the procedure so that the angle of elevation is the correct one.